# Is it idiomatic to say "you're eating like you're starving"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> **[be starving](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-starving)**  (also be starved American English) to be very hungry
>
> You must be starving!

---

When a person eat quickly and take large mouthfuls of food because he is starving.

What is the idiomatic way to say in English?

In English, people often say "**You must be starving**".

Is there any other ways to say it?

Can I say "**you're eating like you're starving**" (it sounds a lit cumbersome) or "**you're eating like starving**"? Are they idiomatic?

Comment: do you want somethings like "wolf down, pig out on sth, make a pig of yourself"?

Comment: to gobble down your food.